# select rows from pandas dataframe with same values in one column different on the other &find the average&make it a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say i have a dataframe like:

```
     A      B     C   D
1  2010    one    0   0
2  2020    one    2   4
3  2007    two    4   8
4  2010    one    8   4
5  2020    four   6  12
6  2007    three  7  14
7  2006    four   7  14
```

And i want to get colum C values of the same column A values , find the average and make it a dictionary so that my output would look like:

```
{  "2006": 14, "2007": 11,"2010":2 .....}
```

What is the most practical way to solve this? I have about 10,000 rows and it doesn't make any sense of me to write them down one by one.I hope I clearly wrote about my problem.

Comment: looks like you used `D` in your example output, not `C`

Comment: yeah that was a misake :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `groupby`+`mean` to compute the mean per group and `to_dict` to convert to dictionary:

```
df.groupby('A')['C'].mean().to_dict()
```

output: `{2006: 7.0, 2007: 5.5, 2010: 4.0, 2020: 4.0}`

Comment: I think this is spot on, no?

Comment: @sophocles I could not understand your comment, until I saw there was a DV, thanks ;)